# Proper settings for Keeping SignalR connection Alive

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have a page using signalR, and its also using flash/html5 on it.  After a certain amount of time the user seems to go "idle" and get disconnected, or the connection isn't alive anymore because I cant receive messages.  If I wanted to keep the connection alive as long as the browser is open, what would be the proper configuration.  My configuration right now for keeping it alive is as follows:

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
```

Using SignalR 0.5.3

Comment: As Taylor stated, this is on by default for everthing except longpolling (because we don't support it there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update to 1.0Alpha this is taken care of for you 99% of the time.(via https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/469).